# Reading stdout from a running script with Python

Tags: python, stdout, pipe, stdin

I have some trouble with python. I am trying to get output from a running script and use it in another script. So, what I want to do is something like this;

Suppose the `out.py` and `in.py` like these;

```
# out.py
def main():
    while True:
        print "test"
        time.sleep(10)
main()

# in.py
text = sys.stdin.readline()
print "hello " + text
```

I want to run scripts like this,

```
$ python out.py | python in.py
```

but, this hangs and prints nothing instead printing "hello test" every 10 seconds. From this, I am guessing that `|` waits until the `out.py` terminates. All right then, what if I want to use in.py with a daemon?

My actual problem is; I'm trying to get output from [arpwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpwatch). arpwatch is running as daemon, and send ip/mac pairings to the stderr. I want to get that output and parse it; so, I need something like this;

```
$ arpwatch | python myscript.py
```

to achive this, how should i code `myscript.py`? I have tried to use [subprocess module,](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) but I had no success again. I hope I could clearly explain my problem since my English is decent.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is one of buffering. It goes away if you explicitly flush stdout in `out.py`:

```
import sys
import time

def main():
    while True:
        print "test"
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(10)
main()
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to rely on `arpwatch` doing this itself; if it doesn't, you'll want to try [PTYs](http://docs.python.org/library/pty.html) instead of pipes, since those count as terminals and will cause most applications to use line buffering instead of block buffering.

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply. works like a charm :) i'll look at pty's for arpwatch.

Comment: @MuhammetCan: you're welcome. Forget what I said about `pexpect`, you won't need that when you're only reading a process's stdout; the `pty` module will suffice.